Authenticity of Hadith About Shepherd being killed?
My question is related to the following Hadith where a group of men were killed as a form of punishment because they killed innocent shepherd. The Hadith in question is this one:-
Anas said, "Some people of Ukl or Uraina tribe came to Medina and its climate did not suit them. So the Prophet (ﷺ) ordered them to go to the herd of (Milch) camels and to drink their milk and urine (as a medicine). So they went as directed and after they became healthy, they killed the shepherd of the Prophet and drove away all the camels. The news reached the Prophet (ﷺ) early in the morning and he sent (men) in their pursuit and they were captured and brought at noon. He then ordered to cut their hands and feet (and it was done), and their eyes were branded with heated pieces of iron, They were put in 'Al-Harra' and when they asked for water, no water was given to them." Abu Qilaba said, "Those people committed theft and murder, became infidels after embracing Islam and fought against Allah and His Apostle ." [Sahih Al-Bukhari, 233]
According to THIS SOURCE and THIS SOURCE, Holy Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alaihi'wa'alahi'wa'ssallam        ) ordered that those men should be killed in such a manner because those men from Ukl or Uraina tribe brutally murdered the shepherd. Those men shoved spikes in the eyes of that shepherd and they also cut his legs and arms. Moreover, those men from Ukl or Uraina tribe also terrorized people, committed theft, and also raped women.
However, the author has obtained this information from Seerah sources such as Tabaqat Al-Kubra, Jam'i At-Tabari, Kitab Al-Maghaz by Waqidi, and Seerah Ibn Hisham.
My Main Question is this:-
I need to know the authenticity of the account that states that those men from Ukl tribe or Uraina tribe pierced the eyes of the Shepherd or cut his hands and feet, as authentic Hadith in Sihah Sitta never mention that. The authentic version of Hadith mentions that those men committed theft, murder, and apostasy. However, how authentic are the reports that state that those men pierced thorns into the eyes of shepherd or they cut his hands and feet and cut his hands and feet?

See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80085/

@UmH - Jazakallah brother
